# P&T Assets + Carthrob

Tags: assets, cartthrob

Has anyone ever tried using P&T Assets as a field with Carthrob? More specifically, I'm looking to sell photos that are located on my Amazon S3 account. Do you think this will work?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this using the `{exp:cartthrob:is_purchased_item}` tag.
https://cartthrob.com/docs/tags_detail/is_purchased_item/index.html

You could just check whether or not the logged in member has purchased the product, and conditionally display the assets.